# elasticsearch query for parameter(string) with multiple values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have the dump of elasticsearch in which a field named as "journey"
under that i have multiple values like, Indian, Australia, Dubai etc.,.
I need to write a query for which i will provide list of journey values that are to be returned (like India and dubai in above example)
I have written a code like this

```
{
         "filter": {
         "terms": {
            "journey": [
               "India",
               "Dubai"
            ]
         }
       }  
      }
```

but i an not getting the results.

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your `journey` field?

Comment: tour": {
                  "properties": {
                     "journey": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },

Answer (score 0):

Since your field is analyzed, it's been lowercase at indexing time.

So your query needs to look like this instead:

```
{
   "query": {
     "terms": {
        "journey": [
           "india",
           "dubai"
        ]
     }
   }  
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample document that you would like to match?

Comment: Did you see my previous comment?